# How do I make something launch graphically as root without going to the command line and running sudo?

Tags: permissions, rhel, eclipse

I can't save anything because of a Permission Denied error.  Do I have to use sudo before I run any program, like `sudo gedit`?  I can run Eclipse as root, but I am trying to see what the correct way to launch everyday applications like gedit, files, Eclipse, etc.  If I'm non-root, how do I make something launch graphically as root without going to the command line and running sudo.  Should I be running everything as root to save things?

I'm using Red Hat 7.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be root to save everyday files.  `sudo` should only be needed for things like system configuration files.  What files are you trying to save that are giving you permission errors?

Comment: Anything I do it makes me use sudo.  I can't save anything, text files, and in my own directory.

Comment: Then your real problem is that your permissions are wrong.  Ask a new question about how to get your permissions straightened out, and include the output of `ls -ld $HOME`.  Also include the steps you take to edit a file.

Answer (score 0):

gksudo yourCommand yourArguments

If you add it to your panel, then you will not need to go into the command line to execute the command.

Comment: Looks like @johnny is running RHEL, which doesn't have a gksudo in it.